# Order "Send Mail" Button not working properly Magento 2

Tags: magento2, order-email, send-mail

When I press the **Send Email** Button from order, it sometimes does not give any response, but by clicking multiple times it works.

Any suggestions what might be the cause of this? Or which files to search for this issue.

Comment: at start not working might be because it's waiting for component to be loaded